# Laravel 5.2.29 multiauth using Auth::guard('one'),Auth::guard('two')

Tags: php, laravel

Please help me to resolve this problem

I want to use multi authentication.

My Laravel version is 5.2.* (5.2.29)

I do all that is written in the documentation

```
//congig/auth.php
<?php

return [

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'adminProvider',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'adminProvider' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
],

'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
];

 But 
 Auth::guard('api')->attempt(['email'=>som@email.com,...])
```

It gives the following error

> FatalErrorException in AuthController.php line 34:
>
> > Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::attempt()
> >     What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change the following :

```
'admin' => [
    'driver' => 'token',
    'provider' => 'adminProvider',
],
```

to

```
'admin' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'adminProvider',
],
```

you can not use attempt with token.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much .
Your answer helped me to resolve this problem

Comment: Sorry,but i don't know how to do that

Comment: in left side of where i have answered your question there is zero between two arrows, please hit the up arrow and click on tick under the down arrow @VanyaAvchyan

Comment: I did it because I really believe this answer exhaustively.
Thank you again

Comment: If you have time, please reply to this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520419/laravel-5-2-29-errors-always-empty